# How to convert string into complex number in python?

Tags: python, type-conversion, complex-numbers

I want to create a special calculator using python but for doing this I should know more about complex numbers. My calculator must get a string and output complex equation. Please help me.

```
myinput = "5 + 2j"
myoutput = ConvertToComplex(myinput) * (3 + 12j)  #please help me with writing this function
print(myoutput)
```

Comment: I would suggest using a tuple - With one element being the real component and the other element being the imaginary component. You can the process it as you like

Comment: use a tuple to store the real & imaginary components. then write a function to multiply two such tuples and return another tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is already built into python. You just need to get rid of whitespace first:

```
myinput = "5 + 2j"
mycleaninput = myinput.replace(" ","")
myoutput = complex(mycleaninput) * (3 + 12j)
print(myoutput)
```